# Публикация программы в microsoft store для windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-store

Что мне нужно?
1. Выставить мою бесплатную программу на майкрасофт стор, с включающим внутренную оплату через майкрасофт.
2. И продавать там свой авторский контент.
И так вопрос. Могу ли публиковать там обычный с# приложения .net windows form который я написал с visual studio. И как происходит внутренная оплата из программы?

Comment: [Публикация приложений и игр для Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/publish/)

Comment: @tym32167 тут я не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. можно ли публиковать .exe файл из папки debug написанный в c#?

Comment: я могу ошибаться, так как я не использую Windows Store, я также как и вы, просто погуглил немного. Но магазин предназначен в первую очередь для UWP приложений, то есть если у вас просто голый exe WinForms приложения, то тут вопрос как его туда отправить. Например, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702002/312041) советуют какой то конвертер, вот [тут](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/19/distribute-existing-desktop-applications-via-windows-store-windows-10-pcs-including-new-windows-10-s-configuration/) говорят, что можно запаковать простую прогу в UWP пакет.